# rails select helper without square brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If I create select tag like this `select(:project_id, nil`, in a Rails view file,

in my generated html I get name of select field like `project_id[]` but I want just **project_id**,

how do I do that?

Comment: Why are you worried about the rendered html value for name field in the first place? What are you trying to do?

Comment: It is not clear to my what you try to achieve, but perhaps using `select_tag` instead of `select` might solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set html option `name` for [select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select):

```
select("project_id", nil, Project.all.map {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {}, { name: 'project_id'} )
```

or you can use [`select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) helper:

```
select_tag 'project_id', options_for_select(Project.all.map{ |p| [p.name, p.id] })
```

Comment: select_tag actually worked, couldn't get the first sample to work.